# How to specify UITypeEditor type at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

In my .NET 4.0 WinForms application I have some application settings. These settings contains a specific folder (type of string). To edit these settings I use the `PropertyEditor`.

Here I want that these folder setting is not a string but a folder so the user has a button to select the folder in the property editor. For that I add this line to the `settings.designer.cs` before the declaration of the setting:

> [System.ComponentModel.Editor(typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Design.FolderNameEditor), typeof(System.Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))]*

These is overwritten every time I add a new setting to my application. So my question is how to do this at runtime?

Comment: You cannot edit the Settings.Designer.cs file, it contains auto-generated code and any changes will be lost when the code is re-generated.  So don't do that, use a property in a Form that you display at runtime.  That property's getter and setter can simply use the setting.

Comment: Yes, I know. Thats why I wanna do this in code. But how?